# Find the fundamental solution in tempered distribution

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

I am a beginner of distribution theory.
I would like to find the fundamental solution in the sense of tempered distribution $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbf{R}^3).$(the duality of Schwartz space)
\begin{equation}
 \partial_x E+i\partial_yE+\partial_z^{2}E=\delta, \quad in \quad \mathcal{S}'(\mathbf{R}^3)
\end{equation}
where $\delta$ is the Dirac distribution in $\mathbf{R}^3.$

My attempt is to apply the Fourier transform on both side of the equation in the sense of  $\mathcal{S}'(\mathbf{R}^3),$ we have
\begin{equation}
(i\xi_1-\xi_2-\xi_3^2)\hat{E}(\xi)=1, 
\end{equation}
where $\hat{E} \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbf{R}^3).$
Then what can I do next? Can I divide the above formula by $(i\xi_1-\xi_2-\xi_3^2)$, and do the Fourier inverse transform to $(i\xi_1-\xi_2-\xi_3^2)^{-1}$ to get the answer? Can anybody help me? Thank you so much!

Comment: Is $(i\xi_1-\xi_2-\xi_3^2)^{-1}\in L^1_{loc}$ ?

Comment: It is often better to not take Fourier transform in all dimensions but let one remain a derivative, e.g. take Fourier transform in $x$ and $y$ but not in $z$.

Comment: I think $i\xi_1-\xi_2-\xi_3^2 \in L_{loc}^1.$ If I take Fourier transform in $x$ and $y$, so there is an ODE about $z$, what is the initial value of this ODE at z=0?